# Save and restore QLabels with images in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qlabel

Currently I am using `QLabel`s to display images on the GUI Application I am developing. It works by when the user clicks on the "Add Graphic" button, a new dynamic label is created and appears on the window. When the user double clicks the label, the file dialog opens and the user can select the image to display which works fine.

The requirement of the application is to restore the image when the application shuts down so that the user doesn't have to input the image again, which I am struggling to come up with a solution. I'm trying to use `QBuffer`s and `QSettings` to restore the images but there is a line of code which just crashes the application.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    readSettings();
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Set up the window size
    this->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Raspberry PI GUI v1.0"));

    this->resize(800, 400);

    // Add label Button
    button = new QPushButton("Add Graphic", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 20), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(input_label()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::input_label()
{
    Label *label = new Label(this);
    label->setText("New Graphic");
    label->show();
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QByteArray bArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    this->label->pixmap()->save(&buffer, "PNG"); // This line of code is crashing everything

    QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");
    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    settings.setValue("image", bArray);
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
     QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");

     settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
     QByteArray image = settings.value("image", QByteArray()).toByteArray();
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    writeSettings();
    event->accept();
}
```

**label.cpp**

```
#include "label.h"

//---------------------------------------
// Deconstructor
//---------------------------------------
Label::~Label()
{
}

void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Move the coordinates on the main window
    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = event->x();
    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = event->y();
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Allow the user to drag the graphics on the Display
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    move(event->globalX()-m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().x(),

        event->globalY()-m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().y());
}

void Label::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //QByteArray bArray;
    //QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
    //buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    //--------------------------------
    // Open file dialog
    //--------------------------------
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images(*.png, *.dxf, *.jpg"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Images"),
        "/home",
        tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));

    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        QImage image(fileName);
        Label::setPixmap(fileName);
        Label::adjustSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: this->label->pixmap() might return 0, which could crash your application. Could you check if a valid pixmap is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QLabel::pixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) returns a null pointer if no pixmap has been set. In the same way, you should check if your properties file has the `image` entry set, and only in that case restore the image.

```
void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    if (this->label->pixmap() != nullptr) {
        QByteArray bArray;
        QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        this->label->pixmap()->save(&buffer, "PNG");

        QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");
        settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
        settings.setValue("image", bArray);
    }
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    QByteArray image = settings.value("image").toByteArray();
    if (!image.isNull()) {
        QPixmap pixmap;
        if (pixmap.loadFromData(image)) {
            this->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

When you create the `QLabel` you are storing it in a local variable, but it is never assigned to `this->label`, thus you probably are accessing garbage when doing any `this->label->...` operation.

```
void MainWindow::input_label()
{
    Label *label = new Label(this);
    label->setText("New Graphic");
    label->show();
    this->label = label; // try with this
}
```

This is a workaround, if this works you must check the rest of logic since then you can be adding several `QLabel`s, but only saving the last one... the same when restoring the state: `this->label` may not be created, so you must create it, as well as to initialize `this->label` to `nullptr` in the constructor.

**Several labels**

For several labels, I'd suggest having a `QList<QLabel*>` container instead of the single `QLabel` member, and saving all of them. When restoring, just programmatically insert a new label before restoring the image.

```
class MainWindow ... {
  // ...
  QList<QLabel*> labels;
  // ...
}

void MainWindow::input_label()
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("New Graphic");
    label->show();
    this->labels.append(label);
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    int i = 1;
    Q_FOREACH(auto label, labels) { // save all existing labels with an image
      if (label->pixmap() != nullptr) {
        QByteArray bArray;
        QBuffer buffer(&bArray);
        buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        label->pixmap()->save(&buffer, "PNG");

        QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");
        settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
        settings.setValue(QString("image-%1").arg(i), bArray);
        ++i;
      }
    }
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Save state", "GUIApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
      QByteArray image = settings.value(QString("image-%1").arg(i)).toByteArray();
      if (!image.isNull()) {
        QPixmap pixmap;
        if (pixmap.loadFromData(image)) {
          input_label(); // add new label
          this->labels.back()->setPixmap(pixmap);
        }
      } else break; // no more images
      ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, I've just tried this out with a loaded image but it's still crashing when closing the application

Comment: Mmm... it's working for me in a small project I've created to do so... is it crashing in the same line? any additional info you can provide?

Comment: BTW, the `QImage image(fileName);` in `mouseDoubleClickEvent` is unnecessary, you are not using it at all.

Comment: I've commented the line "this->label->pixmap()->save(&buffer, "PNG");" in writeSettings() and it's still crashing unfortunately. Could it be something in the closeEvent() part that is causing it to crash?

Comment: No, I think the problem is that `this->label` is uninitialized

Comment: Adding the "this->label" stopped it crashing which is great but the image isn't showing up when I debug the application again, after loading the image to the QLabel.

Comment: Nice! you may need to check the logic, there are other possible points of crash you should care about with that dynamic `QLabel`

Comment: If an image is present in the `QSettings` you have to add the label before restoring the image... check the updated answer

Comment: Check for the multi-QLabels solution... I did it directly on the browser, sorry if there is any typo

Comment: There's 3 errors on the multi-QLabels solution with " this->label.append(label);" and " this->label.back()->setPixmap(pixmap);"

Comment: Lol sorry ;), rookie error, but now the image showing when restarted. Not in the right area placed but I'll try to solve that problem. Thank you heaps for your help :D, I've had to quickly learn QT for a college project.

Comment: Check for the `.move()` method when showing it. It would be better if you add it to a layout or so.

Comment: I'll try and get a code solution that restores the image directly where the user placed it on the screen with coordinates on the application.

Comment: `QLabel::pixmap()` returns a null **pixmap**, not pointer. A pixmap is a value, and that value can be null. A pointer is a different kind of a value - but most definitely it's not a pixmap (nor anything else!).

Comment: Sorry, but the documentation clearly states that it returns a pointer: `const QPixmap *pixmap() const`, probably for performance. On the other hand, yes, most Qt objects have a _null state_ which is very useful to avoid dealing with pointers, for example, `QVariant`, any image related object, `QString` (which is different from the empty string)...

Comment: @cbuchart I've been trying to use the existing code to save and restore the labels at the exact position on the screen by using using a `QPoint position` variable in the `Label` header file but the compiler won't let me access the variable as it's illegal.

Comment: Hi @SahilBora, this is a different question. Answering here would deviate from the original post. I suggest you to publish a new question and the rest of the SO community and me will gladly help you. In this way the knowledge is better organized and other users can benefit from it too.

Comment: @cbuchart Ok no problem I'll do that